# Send email from workflow to email enabled document library

Tags: 2010, workflow, email

Here is some background info:
I was asked to create some new personnel action forms for HR, and then when one is submitted, have it sent in an email to certain recipients. They also want them archived in another location, so I set up an email enabled document library so I could send them there with the workflow.

So I am working with Sharepoint 2010 and I have a list workflow that triggers when a new list item is submitted.  The new item form is a customized Infopath form, and the workflow sends an email with an HTML body that contains all of the form info. I can successfully send the email to regular users and I can successfully send an email from Outlook to the email enabled document library using the library's email address. What I am unable to do is to enter the library's email address as a recipient to the workflow and successfully have the workflow send the email to the library.

workflow -> normal recipient = successful;
Outlook -> email enabled library = successful;
workflow -> email enabled library = failure

I would appreciate any ideas on what I might be overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint cannot email itself. It adds an X-Mailer header into the message that prevents message loops.

[SharePoint Cannot Send Mail to Itself](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2013/03/sharepoint-cannot-send-mail-to-itself/)